# Triggering multiple downstream jobs with corresponding parameters

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

We have a set of build jobs A,B,C and their corresponding deploy jobs X,Y,Z. These deploy jobs have some parameters coming from their build jobs i..e,(A-->X, B-->Y, C-->Z).
So, is there anyway that we could kick off all the build jobs(A,B,C) at once and then wait for the build jobs to finish before triggering the corresponding deploy jobs(X,Y,Z) while passing the corresponding parameters downstream at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

1) Configure jobs A,B & C to trigger deploy jobs X,Y & Z respectively on completion using the below plugin where you can also pass parameters.

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin

**AND**

2) Run a new job lets call it `trigger` that triggers jobs A,B,C at the same time.

**OR**

2) configure the build jobs A,B & C to build periodically for ex. once a day etc

**EDIT**

```
pipeline {
agent {
        label 'slave'
    }
stages{
    stage('Run build jobs'){
        parallel {
            stage('Build job A') {
                steps {
                    build job: 'A', parameters: [string(name: 'duration', value: '10')]    
                }    
            }
            stage('Build job B') {
                steps {
                    build job: 'B', parameters: [string(name: 'duration', value: '10')]    
                }    
            }
            stage('Build job C') {
                steps {
                    build job: 'C', parameters: [string(name: 'duration', value: '1')]    
                }    
            }
        }
    }
    stage('Run deploy jobs')
    {
        steps {
            // Build deploy jobs
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: 1) I assume you've meant, a trigger job for jobs X,Y,Z once the parameters are passed, which means the deploy jobs are triggering twice which is not ideal for our case.

Comment: 2) The 2nd solution will not work for us as we use this pipeline several times a day.

Comment: No I meant what I wrote in the answer. I thought you wanted your build jobs to run and complete before deploy jobs are triggered respectively ?

Comment: @JohnDoe you can trigger your build jobs as many times as you want

Comment: Yes, but the problem here is build jobs A,B,C take different times to get completed. Let's say A and B are taking 10 min each but C is just taking 1 min, so, therefore kicking off the deploy job Z in this case which is not the scenario we are looking for. We want all the build jobs to wait for each other and once those are done we can trigger the deploy jobs. I hope this should clarify the scenario we are looking for.

Comment: Ah OK. That can be achieved using `parallel`. See my edit above. Deploy jobs won't get triggered until all build jobs complete.